# Calabash-Android: Set system time to text field

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I am testing a android app and want to add name to ListView. But I want it to auto generate name which make it unique in the list.

I tried and can add system date to CustomTextView  with code below in console.

```
query("ClearableEditText id:'edt_event_name'", :setText=>`adb shell date`)
```

Then I want to paste these to .feature and .sh file but no idea to make it work.

Any idea please help! 
Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to add them to .featrue and .sh files? Don't you just want to insert it into the fields?

Comment: Cuz everyday I have to run the test case several times and I want to know exactly how it works to print reports. Now I only put a static name on .feature file to run that cause hundreds of item in the list with the same names.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do or having problems doing. You have a number of feature files that you want to run, but some of them have the same name? And is this about executing the right features or is about gathering output in a report?

Comment: Oh I got what u mean. I only have 1 feature file which including all scenarios. And this is about 1 scenario with enter a 'text' into Name, which I want to add system date time to it. And problem is I tried to use 'adb shell date' to that feature file but no work. Tried to add to calabash_steps.rb file but no work too.